# Do dropboxes contain goal explosions?

Tags: rocket-league

I have opened a lot of dropboxes, but I have never once recieved a goal explosion.  Do they even include them?  Are goal explosions only available for credits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do free dropboxes contain goal explosions?**

In general, no.  The standard free dropboxes [only contain uncommon, rare, very rare, and import](https://rocketleague.fandom.com/wiki/Drop#Where_to_Obtain_Drops) drops, and there are [are no standard goal explosions in those rarities](https://rocketleague.fandom.com/wiki/Goal_Explosion)

**Are goal explosions only available for credits?**

There are multiple ways to get goal explosions without paying anything:

- **Playing Tournaments**. Playing in the official tournaments gives you tournament credits, which can be redeemed for random rewards. In [every season so far](https://rocketleague.fandom.com/wiki/Tournaments) it's been possible to get exclusive goal explosions from this.
- **RLCS Fan Rewards**.  By [linking your Rocket League account to Twitch](https://rewards.rocketleague.com/) and watching [RLCS](https://www.twitch.tv/rocketleague), you can get random rewards sometimes, some of which are goal explosions.
- **Season drops**. At the end of the season, you get a reward based on your rank. The reward changes from season to season, but multiple seasons in the past have rewarded goal explosions, and it's likely there will be more in the future.
- **Limited-time events**. Various holiday events have given out free goal explosions in the past, such as the [Halloween](https://rocketleague.fandom.com/wiki/Haunted_Hallows_Series), [Christmas](https://rocketleague.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Santa_Series), and [Easter](https://rocketleague.fandom.com/wiki/Spring_Fever_Series) events.
- **Free shop items**. Occasionally there are free items in the shop you can redeem. At least once in the past, they've given out a free goal explosion.
- **Playing Sideswipe**. They've previously given out a goal explosion as a reward for playing Sideswipe, the mobile version of Rocket League. That promotion is now over, but there may be more in the future.
- **Twitch Prime**. While not actually free, a lot of people already have either Twitch Prime or Amazon Prime. If you have either of these, you can get a free goal explosion from the [Twitch Prime Rewards page](https://gaming.amazon.com/home?ingress=twch).

Comment: thanks for the awesome answer!  I'll look out for them.